# Как при кнопке "Вернуться назад" сохранить вводные данные на предыдущей странице?

Tags: javascript, angular

я ввожу в input личные данные и при клике кнопки "Далее" я перехожу на другую страницу. В другой странице есть кнопка "Вернуться назад". Как сохранить вводные данные на предыдущей странице нажав на кнопку "Вернуться назад"?

Comment: Если это спа, то пользоваться стейт менеджером каким-нибудь. У реакта там редакс есть, у вью вюекс. Что у ангуляра не знаю. Если не спа, то никак. Страница будет перезагружаться, заново выполнять скрипты, заново отрисовывать всё.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это не SPA страницы, то вам нужно повесить обработчики на поля, которые при изменении поля будут записывать значения например в LocalStorage.
При инициализации страницы доставать оттуда значения и устанавливать инпутам

Если SPA и вы используете какой-то фреймворк, то внимательнее почитайте мануалы